# C++ Namespace Convention

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am new to C++.

I have a file that has the following:

```
namespace A {
  namespace B {
     function foo() {
     }
  }
  function bar() {
  }
}
```

and another file has the following:

```
namespace A {
  namespace C {
     // Call foo() and bar() here.
  }
}
```

If I want to call foo and bar inside of namespace C, should I include their absolute namespace?

```
A::B::foo();
A::bar();
```

or I don't have to include the namespace A since they are all inside A?

```
B::foo();
bar();
```

Comment: `C` has acces to the identifiers in the enclosing scope `A`. Therefore `bar()` and `B::foo()` are valid, since `foo` and `B` are in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Are you asking if it's valid code to write `B::foo()`, or whether the convention is to write `B::foo()` rather than `A::B::foo()`? If it's the later, this question might be a bit too opinion-based for Stack Overflow

Comment: @jspcal I see. Thank you.

Comment: @Justin I wanted to ask whether it's valid but now I also wonder what is the convention...

Answer (score 3):

This is a [*name lookup*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) question.

So if you've read this, you'll know the difference between [Unqualified Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) and [Qualified Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup)

So obviously, unqualified lookup is valid here, but if you want to do some work like disambiguation, you may use qualified lookup. So, qualified lookup is always valid when unqualified lookup is valid.(If you can use qualified lookup).

Answer (score 0):

Just little addition. As Constructor said, qualified lookup always generates well-formed code, but that code does not always produce an expected result. Consider this disambiguation example

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(); 
void foo(float);

namespace Boo {
    using ::foo;
    void foo(int a) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << " is here!\n"; }
}

void foo() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << " is here!\n"; }
void foo(int a) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << " is here!\n"; }
void foo(float) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << " is here!\n"; }

using namespace Boo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo();       // no error!
    Boo::foo();  // still same
    //foo(3); // aw, there are three of them. Bad, bad `using namespace`!
    Boo::foo(3); 
    Boo::foo(3.f); 
    return 0;
}
```

namespace `Boo` propagates name `foo` to be `Boo::foo`. We had defined `foo()` after namespace declaration, but prototype declaration required to be known before.

Now imagine that `Boo` is `std`, `foo` prototypes are something like `abs` or `sin` from standard header and are declared that way. Header implementations are allowed to use trick from above. Result of re-definition of names used in standard namespace is described as undetermined, because depending of if `using` was in implementation or not, the program would use standard or user-defined function with no regard to qualified name.

TL;DR: Result of qualified lookup is always correct but is not always well-determined if reserved names are not respected.